# Renderizar páginas dentro do _Layout.cshtml de outros tipos. Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, razor

Estou desenvolvendo basicamente uma espécie de rede social, porém estou com alguns problemas para renderizar páginas dentro da minha página de _Layout.cshtml.

#### `Html`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="header">Você tem @pUser.RequestsToAccept.Count requisições enviadas.</li>
    @{Html.RenderAction("RequestToAccept", "ProfessionalUserHasClient");}
    <li class="footer"><a href="#">Últimas requisições enviadas</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### Esta dando este erro

> A public action method 'RequestToAccept' was not found on controller 'ManyLife.ASP.Areas.Professional.Controllers.ProfessionalUserHasClientController'.

#### Se eu modificar para o RenderPage

```
<li class="header">
    Você tem @pUser.RequestsToAccept.Count requisições enviadas.
</li>
@RenderPage("~/Areas/Professional/Views/ProfessionalUserHasClient/RequestToAccept.cshtml")
<li class="footer"><a href="#">Últimas requisições enviadas</a></li>

{"Erro ao executar a solicitação filho do manipulador 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'."}
```

Não sei se estou fazendo da melhor forma, porém o print abaixo mostra a situação, preciso acessar a "RequestToAccept.cshtml" naquela aba aberta no lado direito, e a cada troca de view recarrega-la, pois ela fica esperando requisições de pedidos de "amizade":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Meu `Controller`

```
[Authorize]
public class ProfessionalUserHasClientController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Dashboard(ProfessionalUser pUser)
    {
        List<SimpleUser> listProfessionalUserHasClient = new List<SimpleUser>();

        using (ProfessionalUserDAO dao = new ProfessionalUserDAO())
        {
            listProfessionalUserHasClient = dao.ListProfessionalHasClient(pUser.IdProfessionalUser);
        }

        return View(listProfessionalUserHasClient);
    }

    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult RequestToAccept()
    {
        ProfessionalUser pUser = Session["ProfessionalUserLogged"] as ProfessionalUser;

        return View(pUser.RequestsToAccept);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RequestSended()
    {
        ProfessionalUser pUser = Session["ProfessionalUserLogged"] as ProfessionalUser;

        return View(pUser.RequestSended);
    }
}
```

NOTA: Esqueci de avisar que usando o `@RenderPage` ele carrega normalmente, porém quando uso o menu da esquerda para chamar outras views de outros controles, diz que eu estou tentando carregar um objeto do tipo SimpleUser em uma View que espera uma Lista de de um objeto tipo `"x"`, sendo que na action que ele deveria passar, ele retorna esta lista normalmente para a View.

Comment: Acredito que o seu problema é que seus métodos no controller são POST. Retire a annotation [HttpPost] do RequestToAccept e tente novamente.

Comment: @Vinícius {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifique:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult RequestToAccept()
{
    ProfessionalUser pUser = Session["ProfessionalUserLogged"] as ProfessionalUser;

    return View(pUser.RequestsToAccept);
}
```

Para:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RequestToAccept()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Atualizei com uma nota em baixo, não sei se você viu, porém este código que você mandou testei e gerou a seguinte exception: {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.} ... a lina que gerou é a @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") do _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Significa que o Bundling está sendo chamado inúmeras vezes, dando estouro de pilha. Tem Bundling nas suas Views? O certo é que o `@Scripts.Render()` fique apenas na View `_Layout`.

Comment: só tem no _Layout mesmo.

Comment: Acho que ele está chamado `_Layout` todas as vezes. Modifiquei a resposta com um atributo a mais. Faça um teste.

Comment: Permaneceu o erro.

Comment: Não sei se você leu a nota que adicionei, por que com o RenderPage ele abre, se eu clicar na aba do Dashboard ele até recarrega perfeito, porém quando clico nas abas de baixo para carregar as actions de outros controllers da aquele erro dizendo que estou passando um objeto (??) diferente do que a View espera (sendo que na action da tal view, ele retorna a lista perfeta). Só que nem entra na view.

Comment: Como estão os `ActionLinks` para os métodos das outras Views?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Pacientes", "List", "ProfessionalHasClient") todos neste padrão.

Comment: É que isso já seria escopo de outra pergunta. Não sei o que está causando isso com o que tenho nesta pergunta.